# How to convert Nginx rules to htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx-location

I'm trying to convert my nginx location rules to htaccess rules.

I got this from online converter https://labs.gidix.de/nginx/

```
RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
location @addslash {
        return 301 $uri/;
    }
location ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ {
        try_files $uri @addslash;
    }
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
location /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$args;
    }
```

**Nginx rule:**

```
 location @addslash {
        return 301 $uri/;
    }

    location ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ {
        try_files $uri @addslash;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$args;
    }
```

Plan to use htaccess with litespeed but no success. I got 500 internal error with the htaccess rule generated.

Comment: Found out .htaccess rule: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
 RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>